# Laravel Eloquent ORM filter with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this model using laravel 5.8: 
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH8p3.png)

I need to get all `Relatorios` from one `User`.
I've already set up relationships with models, this way:

**Cliente**

```
   public function relatorios(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\models\Relatorio');
    }
```

**User:**

```
public function cliente()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Cliente');
   }

   public function grupos(){
       return $this->belongsToMany("App\models\Grupo", "acessos");
   }
```

**Grupo**

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Color');
}

public function usuarios(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'acessos');
}

public function relatorios(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\Relatorio');
}
```

**Relatorio**

```
   public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Cliente');
    }

    public function grupo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Grupo');
    }
```

I need to list all `Relatorios` by `Group` from one `User` and filter by `Cliente`. 
So far, I can do it this way:

```
 $id = auth()->user()->id;
 $obj = User::with('grupos.relatorios.cliente')->get()->find($id);
```

my result is:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "renan",
  "email": "renan.daher@dstec.com.br",
  "email_verified_at": null,
  "cliente_id": 2,
  "created_at": "2019-09-18 18:08:45",
  "updated_at": "2019-09-18 18:08:45",
  "grupos": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "descricao": "Tribut\u00e1rio",
      "color_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-09-13 18:14:58",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-13 18:14:58",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 2,
        "grupo_id": 2
      },
      "relatorios": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "descricao": "Relat\u00f3rio de CDA",
          "link": "www.google.com.br",
          "cliente_id": 1,
          "grupo_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2019-09-16 15:23:45",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-16 15:23:45",
          "cliente": {
            "id": 1,
            "descricao": "PMNI",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
          }
        },
```

However, how can I filter `User-> client_id` with `Report-> client_id`?

---

**Edit Mathieu Ferre changes:**

Thanks for the help, I did something like what you wrote:

```
 $grupos = Grupo::whereHas('relatorios', function($query){
            $id = auth()->user()->id;
            $query->whereHas('cliente', function($query) use ($id){
                $query->where('user_id', $id);
                });
            })->with('relatorios.cliente')->get();

            return $grupos->toJson();
```

And I'm having this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `grupos` where exists (select * from `relatorios` where `grupos`.`id` = `relatorios`.`grupo_id` and exists (select * from `clientes` where `relatorios`.`cliente_id` = `clientes`.`id` and `user_id` = 1)))
```

Comment: Hi XLannes, welcome to SO. I think that [Has one through](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) and [Has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) is what you're looking for if I've understood your question

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the model you want in the end, in this case, `Grupo`

So you have to do something like this:

```php
$grupos = Grupo::whereHas('relatorios', function($query){
    $query->whereHas('cliente', function($query) use ($id){
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
        });
    })->with('relatorios.cliente')->get();
```

and then for displaying it :

```php
foreach($grupos as $grupo){
    foreach($grupo->relatorios as $relatorio){
       $relatorio->cliente
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it that way, but it generated sql error. I edited the main question with the changes

Comment: What link have you beteen your cliente and your user ?  Bascly, you need to to a whereHas on the object linked to your user :)